# How can I limit connections from any IPs but localhost using xinetd?

Tags: linux, networking, xinetd

There is a xinetd service. Users connect to it from their workstations. How can I limit them to use only one connection per IP, but keep unlimited connections from localhost?

I know there is **per_source** option, but it does not make a difference between IPs, it applies to any incoming connection.